# Limiting collection_check_boxes selections in a rails loop

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to limit the check mark selections to a certain number so people can't abuse the category selections.

Here's my attempt from a few examples i ran into.  None work with the loop. I tested it with a regular, manual style checkbox system and it works.  Haven't found any examples where they're using a loop.

```
  <div id="checkbox">
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, :multiple => true) %>
  </div>

  <script>

  $('.checkbox :name').change(function () {
    var $cs=$(this).closest('checkbox').find(':name:checked');
    if ($cs.length > 3) {
        this.checked=false;
    }
});
</script>
```

I would like to limit the checks to, lets say 5.

Suggestions on how I can set up the JS to work with the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about disabling the rest of the unchecked checkboxes if it exceeds a certain number of checked ones?

something like this:

```
$('#checkbox input:checkbox').change(function () {
  var $cs=$('#checkbox input:checkbox:checked');
  if ($cs.length > 3) {
    $('#checkbox input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", true);
  }
  else{
    $('#checkbox input:checkbox').attr("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry, i had the wrong code up.  I edited the post to what my code actually is.  The within the script tags is an example.  I tried a few different variations but the example is just abotu the same.  Not sure how to connect it to the loop since I don't have an input tag.(im not experienced in JS)

Comment: @uno I changed the selectors, but I can't guarantee it'll work, I haven't tested yet. I still find it a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a simple one - is it the missing `#` in your JS?

```
  $('.checkbox :name').change(function () {
    var $cs=$(this).closest('#checkbox').find(':name:checked'); // << see change here
    if ($cs.length > 3) {
        this.checked=false;
    }
  });
```

Without this, it will look for the closest checkbox element up the chain, rather than the container with the ID 'checkbox'.

Let me know if that helps at all :)

Comment: omg, i copypasted the wrong code.  I edited the post.  I originally had the code that actually worked with the no looped check boxes.  sorry